# Nokogiri capturing the correct css selector but selector changes

Tags: ruby, css-selectors, nokogiri

I'm writing a program that will pull the information of our printers from the web and output the vital stuff.

I have some css that changes depending on what the printer's maintenance/toner is at, however what I need to do is capture the css for the `Toner` and not for the `Maintenance`

I have successfully captured the information using this code:
`print "Toner left: ",  page.css('.hpConsumableBlockHeaderText')[1].text, "\n"`

Problem being this only captures the `36%` not the `26%`

Examples:
[image: Maintenance]
[image: Toner]

Notice that both are in the same `span`, I'm lost as how I can capture one and not the other?

Examples of usage:

```
[]$ ruby clean_printer laser15
Toner left: 
Maintenance Kit����31%
110V-Q5421A, 220V-Q5422A

[]$
```

Source (Some info left off for security):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby

require 'colored'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'restclient'

class CleanPrinter

  attr_accessor :printer, :amount

  def initialize(printer, amount)
    @printer = printer
    @amount = amount.to_i
  end

  def check_argv
    if ARGV[0] == nil || ARGV[1] == nil
      puts <<-EOF

      USAGE: clean_printer <printer-name> <number-of-copies>
      EOF
      .yellow.bold
    else
      send_print_jobs
    end
  end

  def create_jobs
    system("lp -d #{@printer} test.txt")
  end

  def send_print_jobs
    @amount.times do
      create_jobs
    end
  end

  def parse_4100
    page = Nokogiri::HTML(RestClient.get("#{@printer}.com"))
    #page.css('font').each_with_index { |e,i| puts "Matched at #{i}" if e.text =~ /6%/ } <= Used to find the correct selector
    print "Toner left: ", page.css('font')[28].to_s[/\d[%]/], "\n"
    powersave = page.css('td')[9].to_s[/(?<=POWERSAVE\ )\w+(?=<)/]
    powersave == "ON" ? (puts "Powersave Mode: ON") : (puts "Powersave Mode: OFF")
  end

  def parse_4350
    page = Nokogiri::HTML(RestClient.get("#{@printer}.com/hp/device/this.LCDispatcher"))
    #page.css('hpConsumableBlockHeaderText').each_with_index { |e,i| puts "Matched at #{i}" if e.text =~ /26%/ }
    print "Toner left: ",  page.css('.hpConsumableBlockHeaderText')[1].text, "\n"
  end

  def parse_brother
  end
end

mr_clean = CleanPrinter.new(ARGV[0], ARGV[1])
mr_clean.parse_4350
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Discovered that using this regex: `[/\d{1,3}[%]/]` will capture the `31%` from the Maintenance

```
[]$ ruby clean_printer laser15
Toner left: 31%
[]$
```

Comment: "Notice that both are in the same `span`." Well... no. They're in two different `span`s which both happen to have the same `class` attribute. Presumably `page.css('.hpConsumableBlockHeaderText')` returns both elements, but you're using `page.css('.hpConsumableBlockHeaderText')[1]`, which will return the second one, when it seems like you want the first. Have you tried `[0]` instead?

Comment: @Jordan I have not I'll try that really quick

Comment: Glad it was helpful! I've posted an answer.

Comment: Please do not use images to display HTML or data. We can't use that to create test cases or use it in answers without typing it in. Instead, summarize the HTML to the bare minimum necessary to demonstrate your code's problem. Anything else wastes our time, slowing our answers, or worse, discourages attempts to answer. You have to help us help you.

Comment: @theTinMan My bad, will do next time, chief..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably `page.css('.hpConsumableBlockHeaderText')`returns both elements, but you're using `page.css('.hpConsumableBlockHeaderText')[1]` which will return the second one, when it seems like you want the first. Try this instead:

```
page.css('.hpConsumableBlockHeaderText')[0]
```

Comment: Just use `page.at('.hpConsumableBlockHeaderText')`.